# Qt how to connecto Line Edit to progress bar

Tags: c++, qt

I am very new to QT and C++, I am trying to connect Line edit to progress bar so when I enter some integer value to the Line Edit, progress bar will show it. I could not achieve it. This is what I was trying:

```
    connect(ui->batterycapacity,&QLineEdit::textChanged, ui->progressBar,ui->progressBar->setValue(ui->batterycapacity->text().toInt()));
```

or this:

```
    connect(ui->batterycapacity,&QLineEdit::textChanged, ui->progressBar,ui->progressBar->&QProgressBar::setValue(ui->batterycapacity->text().toInt()));
```

batterycapacity is my Line Edit. How can I connect those 2 together? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. As the signal's argument differs from the slot's argument you need to adapt it with `toInt`, but you cannot simply stick arbitrary code in an argument and expect C++ to execute it when the signal changes.

You need to wrap your snippet in a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```cpp
connect(ui->batterycapacity, &QLineEdit::textChanged, ui->progressBar,
  [=](const QString& text) {
    ui->progressBar->setValue(text.toInt()));
  });
```

The lambda will receive the argument of the `textChanged` signal and pass that to the `setValue` method.
The `[=]` bit at the front tells the compiler to capture the value of `ui` by value so it is accessible inside the lambda.