# QT how to pass variables to main window

Tags: c++, qt

I am very new to QT and C++, I need to pass some variables to main window ( i.e: int a, double b, int c ...). Over the internet they say using global variables is not an appropriate way to achieve it. So I need to use signal-slot approach. But I have no idea how to use signal slot to pass variables to different window. In that case should I declare slot in the current window and slot to another window? Would something like this work:

```
//somewhere in the current window
 int a=10;
 connect (&a, &QPushButton::pressed(), mainwindow, &b);

//In main window
int b;
```

Comment: If you just want to set a variable somewhere you can connect the `pressed` signal to a lambda like [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59452553/qt-how-to-connecto-line-edit-to-progress-bar)

Comment: But how am I going to connect it to a differen variable in another window? Lets say variable is a. And is there an easier way than lambda method? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt, communication between UI components happens using signals and slots.
Thus, you should communicate that some variable changed using a signal:

```
class SomeWindow : public QWindow {
private:
    int a;
signals:
    void aChanged(int a);
// more, of course.
}
```

In some event handler of the `SomeWindow` class, you would have:

```
a = someInput.toInt();
emit aChanged(a);
```

In another window you would, for example, want to synchronize its own `a_copy` variable:

```
class AnotherWindow : public QWindow {
private:
    int a_copy;
public slots:
    void aChangedHandler(int a);
// more, of course.
};

void AnotherWindow::aChangedHandler(int a) {
    a_copy = a;
}
```

Finally, you tie these together using `QObject::connect`:

```
QObject::connect(someWindow, &SomeWindow::aChanged, anotherWindow, &AnotherWindow::aChangedHandler);
```

Sometimes it makes sense to propagate the signal into `AnotherWindow` so that you can attach more handlers to it from inside the class. In that case you would create an `aChanged(int a)` signal in `AnotherWindow` and connect the `SomeWindow::aChanged` signal to it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The things I couldn't figure out 1) Do we need to put Qobject before connect? In the previous question we did not add it. 2) while connecting it does not let me add mainwindow instead of anotherWindow part. Am I missing something?

Comment: 1) The fully-qualified version also works if your current class is not an instance of QObject. I never use the `connect` method form. For 2, you will need to show code as well as the error.

Comment: Code is :  QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(batterySocChanged()), MainWindow(),&MainWindow::batterydone(int a));     And the error is: call to non-static function without an object argument.

Comment: Actually this line of code does not work either: QObject::connect(this,&BatteryWin::batterySocChanged(), MainWindow(),&MainWindow::batterydone(int a));

Comment: Please don't use the old `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. They only fail at runtime and are hard to debug. Second: QObject::connect wants two (object pointer, function pointer) pairs. The function pointer is simply the name, without its argument list, so `&MainWindow::batterydone`. Adding parentheses turns it into a call. If you need to target a specific overload of `batterydone`, see the [`qOverload`](https://devdocs.io/qt~5.11/qtglobal#qOverload) helper.

Comment: Alright thanks I got rid of the calling parentheses. Now it only says 'MainWindow' does not refer to a value. Code is     QObject::connect(this,&BatteryWin::batterySocChanged, MainWindow,&MainWindow::batterydone);

Comment: I'm not psychic, sorry. I don't know how you named the pointer to your main window. Do you even *have* a pointer to it in your `BatteryWin`? Please show code.

Comment: Actually I couldn't put a pointer. I tried to add this:   MainWindow *mainwin; under the private: part of the header of the BatteryWin. However, it gave me error so I did not put a pointer.

Comment: We're getting off-topic here. Please post a new question and *show code* so we can help you instead of guessing.

Comment: It seems too basic to open a new topic though. Can you just tell me how to open a pointer for a MainWindow?

Comment: Once again: I do not have your code in front of me. I do not know how many windows you have or how you created this `BatteryWin` window. I do not know the structure of your code. Without all that information I cannot help you "open a pointer for a MainWindow".